# please help me... i want to using wikitude(android Plugin)

Tags: cordova, wikitude

I have been developing phonegap.

Here I want to add augmented reality.

So I was attached to Wikitude.

However, this does not work.

What should I do in phonegap wikitude plugin can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that but, don't using wikitude plugin.

I used native camera preview.

Phonegap -> native camera preview -> another activity.

So.. that is perfect.